# Criteria Builder In query for list of string

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am passing following json from front end :

```
{names: 'ABC MKL-56-2,ABC MKL-56-3'};
```

In service layer,I am trying to run `in` query with the help of criteria builder as follows :

```
public List<APDetails> getWP(String names) {
        CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<APDetails> query = builder.createQuery(APDetails.class);
        Root<APDetails> root = query.from(APDetails.class);
        Predicate hasA = builder.in(root.get(APDetails_.names).in(Arrays.asList(names.split(","))));
        query.where(builder.and(hasA));
        List<APDetails> APs = em.createQuery(query.select(root)).getResultList();
        return APs;
    }
```

I am getting following error :

```
Error message: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: 
unexpected token: in near line 1, column 163 [select generatedAlias0 
from com.app.ow.APDetails as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias0.names in (:param0, :param1) in ()]
```

Comment: What is the type of the variable `APDetails_.names`? `String`? `List<String>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you're using springboot, I suggest you extend the `JpaSpecificationExecutor` class (check [here](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/), [here](https://dzone.com/articles/using-spring-data-jpa-specification), and [here](https://attacomsian.com/blog/spring-data-jpa-specifications) for more information) from your `APDetailsRepository` (I believe you're using them somewhere...):

```
public interface APDetailsRepository extends JpaRepository<APDetails, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<APDetails> {
```

Then, try this:

```
@Autowired
public APDetailsRepository apDetailsRepository;

........

public List<APDetails> getWP(String names) {
    List<String> namesAsList = Arrays.asList(names.split(","));

    List<APDetails> listAPDetails = this.apDetailsRepository.findAll(createSpecification(namesAsList));

    return listAPDetails;
}

 public Specification<APDetails> createSpecification(List<String> names) {
    return new Specification<APDetails>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<APDetails> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

            if (names!= null && !names.isEmpty()) {
                List<Predicate> predicatesNames = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

                for (String name : names) {
                    predicatesNames.add(builder.equal(root.<String>get("names"), name));
                    //I believe that the "APDetails_.names" attribute is a String...
                }

                predicates.add(builder.or(predicatesNames.toArray(new Predicate[] {})));        
            }

            return builder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {}));
        }
    };
}
```